How to localize conditional String
I'm currently localizing my app from English to German. However, I've encountered difficulties when localizing conditional operators like this one:
Text("Status: \(bluetoothManager.isConnected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected")")

I attempted to localize only the strings, but unfortunately, that approach didn't solved the issue.
Best regards,
Julian
Already tried:

localize only the strings e.g "Connected" = "Verbunden";


See How to deal with localized conditionnel expression within strings

I switched from the legacy string file to the newer string catalog, which solved all issues for me.

You can use the Swift function called NSLocalizedString.
Text("Status: \(bluetoothManager.isConnected ? NSLocalizedString("Connected", comment: "") : NSLocalizedString("Disconnected", comment: ""))")


Okay thank you! This is working, but that not: Text(bluetoothManager.isConnected ? NSLocalizedString("Disconnect", comment: "") : NSLocalizedString("Connect", comment: ""))
